# Deleted files causing my phone to function incorrectly?

Tags: data-recovery, restore

I accidentally deleted files from a folder located on my Android phone and now my phone isn't functioning properly. If I replace those files will my phone now function correctly? Should I replace the deleted files?

Comment: Depends on the file. You'll probably get better answers if you give more information.

Comment: On the phone internal storage or the SD card?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, yes.  You should try it at least.